# Qt Using QRegularExpression multiline option

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregularexpression

I'm writing a program that use QRegularExpression and MultilineOption, I wrote this code but matching stop on first line. Why? Where am I doing wrong?

```
QString recv = "AUTH-<username>-<password>\nINFO-ID:45\nREG-<username>-<password>-<name>-<status>\nSEND-ID:195-DATE:12:30 2/02/2015 <esempio>\nUPDATEN-<newname>\nUPDATES-<newstatus>\n";

QRegularExpression exp = QRegularExpression("(SEND)-ID:(\\d{1,4})-DATE:(\\d{1,2}):(\\d) (\\d{1,2})\/(\\d)\/(\\d{2,4}) <(.+)>\\n|(AUTH)-<(.+)>-<(.+)>\\n|(INFO)-ID:(\\d{1,4})\\n|(REG)-<(.+)>-<(.+)>-<(.+)>-<(.+)>\\n|(UPDATEN)-<(.+)>\\n|(UPDATES)-<(.+)>\\n", QRegularExpression::MultilineOption);

qDebug() << exp.pattern();

QRegularExpressionMatch match = exp.match(recv);
qDebug() << match.lastCapturedIndex();
for (int i = 0; i <= match.lastCapturedIndex(); ++i) {
    qDebug() << match.captured(i);
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Manual says that `MultilineOption` changes behavior only regarding `^` and `$` and your expression doesn't contain them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is you should use `.globalMatch` method rather than `.match`.

See [QRegularExpression documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#global-matching) on that:

> Attempts to perform a global match of the regular expression against
>   the given subject string, starting at the position offset inside the
>   subject, using a match of type matchType and honoring the given
>   matchOptions. The returned QRegularExpressionMatchIterator is
>   positioned before the first match result (if any).

Also, you can remove the `QRegularExpression::MultilineOption` option as it is not being used.

Sample code:

```
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = exp.globalMatch(recv);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I google'd this question having similar issue, but I couldn't agree completely with an answer, as I think most of the questions about multi-line matching with new QRegularExpression can be answered as following:

use QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption option which allows (.) to match newline characters. Which is extremely useful then porting from QRegExp

Answer (score 0):

you got an `or` Expression and the first one is true, job is done.
you need to split the string and loop the array to compare with this Expression will work i think.

If the data every times have the same struct you can use something like this:

`"(AUTH)-<([^>]+?)>-<([^>]+?)>\\nINFO-ID:(\\d+)\\n(REG)-<([^>]+?)>-<([^>]+?)>-<([^>]+?)>-<([^>]+?)>\\n(SEND)-ID:(\\d+)-DATE:(\\d+):(\\d+) (\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+) <([^>]+?)>\\n(UPDATEN)-<([^>]+?)>\\n(UPDATES)-<([^>]+?)>"`

21 Matches